# Xcode Framework goes missing after relaunch. Why?

Tags: xcode6, ios-frameworks

I had Parse working a moment ago.  But after some time had passed and I relaunched the application (via simulator) I got the following runtime error:

[image]

1) I checked the available frameworks and all appear be okay:
[image]

2) I checked Xcode's project navigator and all frameworks appear to be present:
[image]

What am I missing here?

---

Hint/Clue: 
Xcode says it wasn't where it supposed to be.

So I checked the the Xcode's build phase to see that it parse.framework was missing.

So again, I did a '+' to add the parse.framework to the Linked-Binary Library and rebuilt the application.  And it worked.

However, I loose the link when exiting Xcode 6: 
Hence upon relaunch Xcode & rebuilding the app, it crashes AGAIN.
[image]

This time I moved the parse.framework (and associated frameworks) into Apple's Framework directory, with the others.   Then I attempted to re-install parse.framework.

But again, I got the problem.  So I went deeper, looked at the projpbx.prj innards to find:

```
buildSettings = {
                ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME = AppIcon;
                ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_LAUNCHIMAGE_NAME = LaunchImage;
                CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES = YES;
                FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = (
                    "$(inherited)",
                    /Users/Ric/Downloads/Parse,  <--- not reset.  old.
                    Library,
                    /Users/Ric/Downloads/Parse,<--- not reset.  old.
                    Library,
                );
                GCC_PRECOMPILE_PREFIX_HEADER = YES;
```

So...

It looks like a I have a corrupt project file.

Here's the replacement:

```
/* Parse.framework */ ...
 name = Parse.framework; path = System/Library/Frameworks/Parse.framework; sourceTree = SDKROOT; };
```

And here's the reality:
[image]

Safe remedy?... 
How do I make the parse.framework addition PERSISTENT?

Comment: I recommend you to check the "Library search path" in "build settings".

Comment: I've check it...didn't see anything out of the ordinary.   I'm concerned that I'm polluting my project by mucking around there.  I posted a parallel problem about -FLibrary complaint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27008329/how-do-i-resolve-what-particular-directory-xcodes-flibrary-is-complaining-abou