# How do I resolve what particular directory Xcode's -FLibrary is complaining about?

Tags: xcode, path, frameworks

I having library problems. 
Specifically I can't add parse.framework to my project without corrupting the project. 
Below is a snapshot of the  problem.

[image]

Here's the project's Framework Library Search Path:
[image]

How do I find what 'directory' Xcode is having trouble with, and remove it from consideration... so I can clear any gremlins before attempting to add the Parse.Framework again?

Answer (score 0):

Your snapshot is not clear so not able to see what exact problem you are facing. But from the description of it, it looks like that your compiler is not able to locate the framework for you. So try this::

- Remove the framework from you project, just delete it completely.
- Clean your project.
- Add it again.